# how get latest record (MaxDate) for specified related dimension / metric in Datastudio?

Tags: looker-studio

I have this table

```
Country,date, confirmed
"Brazil",2020-05-20,19694
"Brazil",2020-05-21,18508
"Brazil",2020-05-22,20803
"Russia",2020-05-20,8764
"Russia",2020-05-21,8849
"Russia",2020-05-22,8894
...
```

How can I create new Metric field ( formula) to show latest record of  Confirmed cases for specified Country ?
I would like to create new column in my report...

For latest date I can use Max(date), but how it implement to formula ?

so from SQL will be something like > select * where date=Max(date)...
But how achieve this in DataStudio ?